# Why isn't NVIDIA Linux modules part of the NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, packaging, metapackages

I noticed that I had to manually install a `linux-modules-nvidia-*` package, and it doesn't come bundled with NVIDIA drivers.  Why is that?

Comment: The package description of [`linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-modules-nvidia-450-generic) (and other similar packages) says "Extra drivers". Why did you have to install it at all?

Comment: It was a while back, but I installed it because I was hoping I can make the boot up and shutdown screen look good (like with AMD and Intel GPUs).  Didn't work, though.  Though there wasn't any negative impact so I left it behind.

Comment: @muru - Would you know when are the "extra drivers" needed? What is their use?